# Implementing error and state checking with OnBlur

Tags: reactjs

In the following code:

```js
<TextField
   onClick={this.changeVState(validState)}
   {
     this.state.text=== "" ? (this.error, this.helperText ="Please enter a project name!") : null
   }
   onBlur={!validState && this.state.text === "" ? this.state.isValid = false : this.state.isValid = true}
   margin="dense"
   id="projectName"
   label="Project Name"
   variant="outlined"
   defaultValue={this.state.project_name}
   fullWidth
   onChange={(e) => this.editProjectNameHandler(e)}
/>
```

I want onBlur to display an error on top of this
[text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12S5u.png) when the user doesn't enter a valid project name or the project name is empty.
changeVState(validState) changes a state variable to true when the user clicks on the TextField.

I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT3kH.png) with the code.
What I want to know is why am I getting this error, and is there an easier way to implement error/state validation with onBlur?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code. If you want to, I could step you through them and explain why they're issues and how to improve them. In this case, please let me know. I don't mind doing so, but it is quite time consuming, so I won't do so preemptively.

If you just want something that compiles and fixes your case, you can refer to the below component. This is how I would write something like this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { TextField } from "@mui/material"

export default function TestFile() {
  const [validState, setValidState] = useState(false)
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState("Default Project Name")

  const helperText = validState ? null : "Please enter a project name!"

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{helperText}</h1>
      <TextField
        onBlur={() => setValidState(projectName !== "")}
        margin="dense"
        id="projectName"
        label="Project Name"
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue={projectName}
        fullWidth
        onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```